# How to remove popup alert dialog on server errors?

Tags: javascript

Ok, this might sound like a very confusing post, but here's my problem.

I have got a custom chat script on my site which automatically refreshes the chat messages each X seconds. The problem is, if for some reasons I've got a temporary downtime while the script runs, an alert dialog appears at the top, similar to this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFzcY.png saying the server returned a 520 error. Now, the website works perfectly and loads fine. It's just that if there's a temporary downtime which happens in the same milliseconds in which the chat refreshes, I get that error and it's quite annoying as it happens at least 5 times every day, and I'm forced to refresh the page or to click the OK button in order to close it.

I wanted to get rid of it but I'm very confused about where and what to look for.

Any suggestions?

Thank you so much.

Comment: without seeing any code, it is impossible to provide help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure it's the right function, but here you go: https://pastebin.com/qH1BbWpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I needed this code:

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

before my script. It worked like a charm, disabling all the alerts from my script.

Comment: Strange, your screenshot doesn't look like an alert. But I am glad that you found solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

Turn popup dialog off using this script

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that and I'll let you know!

Comment: Shall I add this script at the <head> section or any position doesn't matter?

Comment: I don't know how and where your code actually placed. Present at least some code where you including source code.

Comment: I'm including the chat scripts in the <head> section of the website, so I guess I should add your script before it gets loaded, right?

Comment: Try to add this after `.chat` created - after 55th row

Comment: Thank you I will try. If that doesn't work. Is there a way I could debug it in the exactly same moment it happens? Maybe using Google Inspect Element to debug the error? Thanks in advance, you're very kind.

Comment: If you would provide link to your website, I'll try to go through debug. You're welcome (: